# Search for MACRO definitions in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, search, visual-studio-2012, macros

I have a line of code like

```
#ifdef _TestMacro
```

When I hover the mouse over _TestMacro, Visual Studio shows `#define _TestMacro 1`.
When I try to use Go To Definition or Go To Declaration, nothing happens.
When I try to use Find All References, I only get results with `#ifdef _TestMacro`.

How can I find where `#define _TestMacro 1` is located?

Comment: Have you checked the project settings?

Comment: Identifiers that begin with an underscore are reserved for the implementation so you must not use them in your own code.  I don't know whether this explains your current issue but it is worth knowing that strange things may happen if you are messing with such macros.

Comment: @Praetorian Where should I look?  I tried looking in the Property Page of the project under Common Properties for User Macros, but User Macros was not there.

Comment: Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions (on VS2013)

Comment: @Praetorian OK.  I've found _TestMacro in the location you mentioned.  However, it's value is not set there.  Any other ideas where it's value is set?  Is it common to read these values in from an initialization file?

Comment: @user3731622 Actually that is where the value is set. For anything in that location, Visual Studio defines it with a value of 1. For reference, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx